# How to find first empty field in Capybara?

Tags: rspec, tdd, capybara, capybara-webkit, specifications

I want to find first empty field in form.

`find("input[name='somename']", text: '').first`

raise an error

`Capybara::Ambiguous:
Ambiguous match, found 5 elements matching css "input[name='somename']" with text ""`

Comment: try to use `first(...)` ([doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method))

Comment: and how to use first, if i need field with name and value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Capybara 2.0, `find` requires that only one element matches the specification. Per http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2012/08/capybara-2-0-upgrade-guide/, you can use `first` with the same specification, as in:

```
first("input[name='somename']", text: '')
```

Although it would obviously be less efficient, you can also use:

```
all("input[name='somename']", text: '')[0]
```